# ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 10) are incompatible

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

```
x_train.shape
```

.................output..............
(172, 1177, 1)

```
x_test.shape
```

.................output..............
(30, 1177, 1)

```
 y_train.shape
```

..................Output................
(172,)

```
y_test.shape
```

..................Output................
(30,)

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Convolution1D(32,2,data_format='channels_last',activation='relu', input_shape=(1177, 1)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D())
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adadelta',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

.....................output.............................

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv1d (Conv1D)             (None, 1176, 32)          96        
                                                                 
 max_pooling1d (MaxPooling1D  (None, 588, 32)          0         
 )                                                               
                                                                 
 flatten (Flatten)           (None, 18816)             0         
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 100)               1881700   
                                                                 
 dropout (Dropout)           (None, 100)               0         
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 10)                1010      
                                                                 
 activation (Activation)     (None, 10)                0         
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 1,882,806
Trainable params: 1,882,806
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

```
model.fit(x_train,y_train,validation_data=(x_test,y_test))
```

***..................................Error Message...................................***

```
    ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 10) are incompatible
```

I am applying CNN Model on textual data; Model is built successfully but at the time of model fitting error message got. I applied many solutions to solve this problem, but none work.

Comment: i also used "loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'" at the time of compilation of model but it also not worked.                  as error: Node: 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy/Cast'
Cast string to int64 is not supported
  [[{{node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/Cast}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1127]

Comment: make sure your labels are integers, not strings.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I don't think so, then you would not get the error about cast string to int.

Comment: can you tell me that how to check the confusion Metrix of the CNN model? i tried "print(confusion_matrix(y_test, mypred))" but it did not work. mypred=model.predict(x_test)